# Adding new entity gives error: EntityCommandCompilationException was unhandled bu user code in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, c#-3.0

I have 5 tables in started projects. If I adds new table (Urun entity) writing below codes:

**project.BAL :**

```
public static List<Urun> GetUrun()
{
   using (GenoTipSatisEntities genSatisUrunCtx = new GenoTipSatisEntities())
   {
      ObjectQuery<Urun> urun = genSatisUrunCtx.Urun;
      return urun.ToList();
   }
}
```

**if I receive data form BAL in UI.aspx:**

```
using project.BAL;


namespace GenoTip.Web.ContentPages.Satis
{
    public partial class SatisUrun : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                FillUrun();
            }
        }

        void FillUrun()
        {
            ddlUrun.DataSource = SatisServices.GetUrun();
            ddlUrun.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlUrun.DataTextField = "Ad";
            ddlUrun.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

I added URun later. error appears ToList method: **EntityCommandCompilationException was unhandled bu user code**

**error Detail:**

> Error 1   Error 3007: Problem in Mapping
>   Fragments starting at lines 659, 873:
>   Non-Primary-Key column(s) [UrunID] are
>   being mapped in both fragments to
>   different conceptual side properties -
>   data inconsistency is possible because
>   the corresponding conceptual side
>   properties can be independently
>   modified.
>     C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GenoTip.Satis\GenoTip.DAL\ModelSatis.edmx   660 15  GenoTip.DAL
>   Error 2   Error 3012: Problem in Mapping
>   Fragments starting at lines 659, 873:
>   Data loss is possible in
>   FaturaDetay.UrunID.
>  An Entity with
>   Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
>   (PK does NOT play Role 'FaturaDetay'
>   in AssociationSet
>   'FK_FaturaDetay_Urun' AND PK is in
>   'FaturaDetay' EntitySet)
>     C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GenoTip.Satis\GenoTip.DAL\ModelSatis.edmx   874 11  GenoTip.DAL
>   Error 3   Error 3012: Problem in Mapping
>   Fragments starting at lines 659, 873:
>   Data loss is possible in
>   FaturaDetay.UrunID.
>  An Entity with
>   Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
>   (PK is in 'FaturaDetay' EntitySet AND
>   PK does NOT play Role 'FaturaDetay' in
>   AssociationSet 'FK_FaturaDetay_Urun'
>   AND Entity.UrunID is not NULL)
>     C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GenoTip.Satis\GenoTip.DAL\ModelSatis.edmx   660 15  GenoTip.DAL
>   Error 4   Error 3007: Problem in Mapping
>   Fragments starting at lines 748, 879:
>   Non-Primary-Key column(s) [UrunID] are
>   being mapped in both fragments to
>   different conceptual side properties -
>   data inconsistency is possible because
>   the corresponding conceptual side
>   properties can be independently
>   modified.
>     C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GenoTip.Satis\GenoTip.DAL\ModelSatis.edmx   749 15  GenoTip.DAL
>   Error 5   Error 3012: Problem in Mapping
>   Fragments starting at lines 748, 879:
>   Data loss is possible in
>   Satis.UrunID.
>  An Entity with Key
>   (PK) will not round-trip when:
>   (PK does NOT play Role 'Satis' in
>   AssociationSet 'FK_Satis_Urun' AND PK
>   is in 'Satis' EntitySet)
>     C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GenoTip.Satis\GenoTip.DAL\ModelSatis.edmx   880 11  GenoTip.DAL
>   Error 6   Error 3012: Problem in Mapping
>   Fragments starting at lines 748, 879:
>   Data loss is possible in
>   Satis.UrunID.
>  An Entity with Key
>   (PK) will not round-trip when:
>   (PK is in 'Satis' EntitySet AND PK
>   does NOT play Role 'Satis' in
>   AssociationSet 'FK_Satis_Urun' AND
>   Entity.UrunID is not NULL)
>     C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GenoTip.Satis\GenoTip.DAL\ModelSatis.edmx   749 15  GenoTip.DAL

Comment: How did you create your model?  Did you mess with the edmx file?

Comment: what do you mean sir???? "How did you create your model? Did you mess with the edmx file"

Comment: @Nix I also have this error, I added the table to the edmx file. I, too, get the following error: `EntityCommandCompilationException was unhandled by user code`. Do you have any idea on how to either revert the changes so that the site works again (prior to adding the table) and how I may correctly add tables to avoid this error in future