# How can I add data in foreign key field in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

How can I give set foreign key value field in Entity Framework. I have Kartlar entity (related from kartlar table). I need simple save method this field but, RehberID, KAmpanyaId,BirimID is foregin Key....

```
public static class SatisServicesUpdateTables
{
    public static void SaveKartlar(int RehberID, int KampanyaID, int BrimID)
    {
        using (GenSatisModuleEntities genSatisKampanyaCtx = new GenSatisModuleEntities())
        {
            Kartlar kartlar = new Kartlar();
            kartlar.RehberReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("genSatisKampanyaCtx.Rehber", "ID", RehberID);
            kartlar.KampanyaReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("genSatisKampanyaCtx.Kampanya", "ID", KampanyaID);
            kartlar.BirimReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("genSatisKampanyaCtx.Birim", "ID", BrimID);
            kartlar.Notlar = "hfhfhfhfhfhfghfghfgfghk";
            genSatisKampanyaCtx.AddToKartlar(kartlar);
            genSatisKampanyaCtx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

But it throws to me : ArgumentException was unhandled by user code

[link text](http://www.ressim.net/upload/3548512e.png)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577856/if-adding-new-entity-gives-error-me-entitycommandcompilationexception-was-unha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of your EntityKey should be your context name, not your varaible name:

```
new System.Data.EntityKey("GenSatisModuleEntities.Rehber", "ID", RehberID);
```

and Rehber should be the name of your EntitySet.